# Reentering serial number in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

Does anyone know how to install a new serial on a working copy of Windows 7 - I get notified that my software is not genuine but cannot reenter the serial

Answer (score 2):

One easy method is to change the key via the command prompt:

1. Click the Start orb
2. Type `cmd` and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open an elevated command prompt.
3. Type in `slmgr.vbs -ipk` *followed by your new key*
4. Type `slmgr.vbs -ato` to re-activate if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to enter a new key when you try to activate Windows.

1. Open **Control Panel**.
2. Go to **System**.
3. Click **Activate Windows**. (In case it is not activated) / Click **Change Product Key** on the lower half (In case it was previously activated).
4. It will ask for a new Serial key.

Comment: It does not give me this option - Instead I get only an option to go online and resolve which means buying a new copy

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the System page and link it here? There will be an option to activate somewhere the page.

Answer (score 0):

go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System "Change product key" is at the bottom.